# Scraping pages with inconsistent lengths in dataframe

Tags: r, rvest, purrr

I want to scrape all the names from [this page](https://www.zorgkaartnederland.nl/huisarts). With the result of one tibble of three columns. My code only works if all the data is there hence my error:

```
 Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:
* Length 20: Columns `huisarts`, `url`
* Length 21: Column `praktijk`
```

How can I let my code run but fill with `Na`'s in `tibble` if the data isn't there.

My code for a pauzing robot later used in scraper function:

```
pauzing_robot <- function (periods = c(0, 1)) {
      tictoc <- runif(1, periods[1], periods[2])
      cat(paste0(Sys.time()), 
          "- Sleeping for ", round(tictoc, 2), "seconds\n")
      Sys.sleep(tictoc)
    }
```

Scraper:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

scrape_page <- function(pagina_nummer) {

  page <- read_html(paste0("https://www.zorgkaartnederland.nl/huisarts/pagina", pagina_nummer)) 

  pauzing_robot(periods = c(0, 1.5))

  tibble(

    huisarts = page %>% 
      html_nodes(".media-heading.title.orange") %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      str_trim(), 

    praktijk = page %>% 
      html_nodes(".location") %>% 
      html_text() %>%
      str_trim(),

    url = page %>% 
      html_nodes(".media-heading.title.orange") %>% 
      html_nodes("a") %>%
      html_attr("href") %>% 
      str_trim() %>% 
      paste0("https://www.zorgkaartnederland.nl", .)
  )
}
```

Total number of pages 445, but for example sake only scraping three:

```
huisartsen <- map_df(sample(1:3), scrape_page)
```

Page 2 seems to be the problem with inconsistent lengths because this code works:

```
huisartsen <- map_df(3:4, scrape_page)
```

If possible with `tidyverse` code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that the third entry on page 2 has two links. Rather than getting each type of item separately, a better approach is to iterate through the divs containing info about each person. Then you can handle missing or multiple items within the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retrieve the list of parent nodes

```
parents <- page %>% html_nodes("li.media")
```

Then parse the parent nodes with function `html_node()`.

```
tibble(
    huisarts = parents %>% 
      html_node(".media-heading.title.orange") %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      str_trim(), 

    praktijk = parents %>% 
      html_node(".location") %>% 
      html_text() %>%
      str_trim(),

    url = parents %>% 
      html_node(".media-heading.title.orange a") %>% 
      html_attr("href") %>% 
      str_trim() %>% 
      paste0("https://www.zorgkaartnederland.nl", .)
  )
```

The `html_node` function will always return a value even if it is just a NA

Comment: I was using `html_nodes` instead of `html_node` (without S).